# Specifying control statements for ibm i ILE C/C++

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange, rpgle

For RPG there's pretty much straightforward mechanism exists, so I can write as follows:

```
ctl-opt debug decedit('.') datedit(*dmy/) 
        option(*srcstmt) bnddir('SOMEBND') 
        alwnull(*usrctl) 
        dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*caller) 
        main(main);
```

How do I write the same settings for ILE C/C++ source?

Or I'm supposed to write it somewhere in installer `CRTBNDCPP` statement paremeters?

Comment: Can you expound more on why you want to use some of these options?  A lot of them don't make sense from a C/C++ language standpoint.  As a language, it was designed to separate the build options from the general language options. Most of the C world uses specific build tools (eg. make) and environments to manage things like the activity groups, binding directories, etc.

Comment: @Player1st my goal was to make C module that behaves exactly like certain module written in RPG. Now I see that those parameters that absent in C compilation command are simply not needed and I can safely ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

In ILE C you will probably always first create a module (CRTCMOD) and then create the program (CRTPGM). You can pass all needed parameters to the compile/create commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in C on the i, but ...

1. You MAY be able to define some compile options using Pramga directives.  See https://ibm.co/2LZD411 for information on the options available there.
2. Some of the options you indicate are unique to RPG or not applicable to C (date format, decedit, & allow null come to mind).
3. I'm kind of surprised there isn't a `BNDDIR` parmaeter on `CRTBNDCPP` command.

Comment: seems like none of options needed are available for C/C++...
that's kinda frustrating.
so have to stick with RPG entrypoint and corresponding `CallP(e) My_c_programm` somewhere inside main to do things

Comment: I'm not sure which options you need specifically but there is a binding directory option on CRTBNDCPP.  For runtime binding, you want RTBND.  If you want to specify the location of source includes, you want INCDIR.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are a bit confused on what these options are all about. Several of them are `RPGLE` specific: `debug`, `datedit`, `option`, `alwnull`, `dftactgrp`, and `main` have no equivalent to `C/C++`. I don't think there is any `C/C++` syntax to specify Activation Group or Binding Directory directly in the source.

Answer (score 0):

@David G : There is also no BNDDIR parameter for CRTBNDRPG. I think that is really missing and needed. Also the OPTION parameter for f. e. *DUPPROC is missing on CRTBND... compile commands.